# Writing a csv file in R with parameter in the file name

Tags: r

I am doing a small log processing project in R. I am trying to write a function that gets a dataframe, and writes it in a csv file with some parameters (dataframe name, today's date.. etc)

I have made some progress but didn't manage to write the csv. I hope the code is reproducible and good.

```
library(dplyr)
wrt_csv <- function(df) {
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(df))
  dfpath <- paste0('"',"./logs/",dfname, "_", Sys.Date(),'.csv"')
  dfpath <- as.data.frame(dfpath)
  df %>% write_excel_csv(dfpath)

}
wrt_csv(mtcars)
```

EDIT- this is a final version that works well. Thanks to Ronak Shah.

```
wd<- getwd()

wrt_csv <- function(df) {
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(df))
  dfpath <- paste0(wd,'/logs/',dfname, '_', Sys.Date(),'.csv')

  df %>% write_excel_csv(dfpath)
}
```

I do however now have a bunch of dataframes that i want to run the function with them. should I make them as a list? this didn't quite work

```
l <- list(df1,df2)

lapply(l , wrt_csv)
```

Any thoughts? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep `dfpath` as string. Try :

```
wrt_csv <- function(df) {
   dfname <- deparse(substitute(df))
   dfpath <- paste0('/logs/',dfname, '_', Sys.Date(),'.csv')
   write.csv(df, dfpath, row.names = FALSE)
   #Or same as OP
   #df %>% write_excel_csv(dfpath)
}

wrt_csv(mtcars)
```

Comment: Thanks. This still gives the error `Browse[1]> wrt_csv(mtcars)
Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart` at least when running from my workstation

Comment: This works fine for me. Why do you have `Browse[1]>` at the beginning? Are you running this in a debugger mode? Make sure `'/logs/'` exists.

Comment: Thanks! There was a debug mode open. For non English characters i prefer to use the `write_excel_csv(dfpath)` variation. However, I still get some error which i think is due to permissions?  `Error in open.connection(path, "wb") : cannot open the connection ` . The folder exists..

Comment: I think you are not using the correct path in this line `dfpath <- paste0('/logs/',dfname, '_', Sys.Date(),'.csv')`. Can you check if the path is correct according to your system?

Comment: I assumed this was  attributed as a sub folder of my wd. I will check

Comment: If you want to apply this to lot of dataframes you can use a `for` loop to do so. If you have difficulty applying it you can ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
wrt_csv <- function(df) {     
   dfname <- deparse(substitute(df))
   dfpath <- sprintf('/logs/%s_%s.csv', dfname, Sys.Date())     
    write.csv(df, dfpath, row.names = FALSE)

 }

wrt_csv(mtcars)
```